# Calculate revenue from each level -neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, relation

I have the following query to find the commission like level1-20%,level2-10%,level 3 - 5% using neo4j using two relations AFFILIATE_TO and PAID like bellow.

```
with [20.0, 10.0, 5.0] as percents
match (i:Instructor)-[r:AFFILIATE_TO*..3]->()-[:PAID]->(t:Payment)
with i, percents[size(r) - 1] as percent, t
with i, t.amount * percent / 100.0 as cut
return i.name as Name, sum(cut) as revenue
```

Here it return the revenue sum of each instructors,Is it possible to calculate the individual revenue from this query.ie,revenue from each level?

**I mean the details Instructor name,revenue sum,20% revenue sum,10% revenue sum,5% revenue sum**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Cypher aggregates or groups by `RETURN` by all the keys you return. So if you want to `RETURN` revenue from each level, you have to `RETURN` level size also, or at least use it in `WITH` statement to groupby.

```
with [20.0, 10.0, 5.0] as percents
match (i:Instructor)-[r:AFFILIATE_TO*..3]->()-[:PAID]->(t:Payment)
with i, percents[size(r) - 1] as percent, t, size(r) - 1 as level
with i, t.amount * percent / 100.0 as cut,level
return i.name as Name, sum(cut) as revenue,level
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i am trying to get the values like Instructor name,revenue sum,20% revenue sum,10% revenue sum,5% revenue sum

Comment: @ShijinTR Shouldn't be hard to modify the query for this, you'll need a variable on the affiliate node, you won't have to perform a SUM() operation, and you can keep the percent variable in scope and return it (with optional formatting) for the percentage. (and level, if you need to return it, can actually just be size(r), no need to subtract from it)